# numpy np.array only returns the first value when asked name.shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a question:

I got DICOM files, 171 of them in a directory. I turned them into pixel arrays and put them in a list with this code:

```
display = []
path = "./path/*.dcm"
for f in glob.iglob(path):
    medical_image = pydicom.dcmread(f)   #pydicom reads the file in f and send it to medical_image
    image = medical_image.pixel_array.astype(float) #turn them one by one into pixel arrays (float)
    display.append(medical_image) #append them to the list
```

ok, so to confirm that it was really getting the files, I typed a

```
len(display)
```

that returned 171, so it's ok

Then, I did

```
display = display.np.array(display)
```

to convert the list into a numpy arry so I could see the files, but turns out that I couldn't and when I type `.shape` it only returns (171,) and I didn't understand why.

I think that if I could see the other variables it would work to display with Matplotlib. Am I right?

Comment: __`image`__ is your numpy array that you want to append to `display`. `medical_image` is the result of `pydicom.dcmread`. You now have 171 objects of whatever `dcmread` returns in your list instead of 171 numpy arrays

Comment: oh, ok, I think I got it, but how can I get 171 numpy arrays instead os 171 objects with no usable format to the numpy np.array?

Comment: Did `np.array(display)` give you any sort of "ragged array" warning?  I think the `display` list has arrays or lists that vary in shape, so it has to make a 1d object dtype array, not a multidimensional numeric one.

Answer (score 0):

and thanks for the comments:
@hpaulj and @Pranav Hosangadi
I got the answer:

```
    folder = './path/'
    imgs = [pydicom.read_file(folder + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(folder)]
    data = np.stack([i.pixel_array for i in imgs])
```